# Minimum surface of revolution when endpoints are very far apart?

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I read that the surface of minimum area, generated by considering curves joining two points and then rotating them about the $x$-axis, which can be expressed as
$$
2\pi\int_{x_0}^{x_1} y \sqrt{1 + (y')^2}dx
$$ is given by a catenary unless the two points are very far apart compared to their distance to the $x$-axis. In that extreme case the area of the surface consisting of the circles on the endpoints plus the segment of the axis between them will be less than any surface of revolution generated by a smooth curve.

But I don't see how this is possible, as at the endpoints the circles are defined by revolving about a single point. In essense, the $dx$ in the integral above is only 'used' at $x_0$ and at $x_1$ and hence area of two circles at the endpoints should be zero?

Comment: The are of a circle has always been, and remains $\pi r^2$. When the surface collapses to the axis, a lot of the surface of the catenary is regained and this compensates the area of the two circles.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But the above integral is over the line from $x_0$ to $x_1$. Circles at the endpoints have width (in terms of $x$) of a single point and hence don't contribute to the integral. So I can't see how this formulation captures the actual area of the circles?!

Comment: You should consider a path integral instead of an explicit form $y=f(x)$.